# KnockoutJS - Click event on template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have the following KnockoutJS template (render with jquery.tmpl):

```
<script id="contactsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="click: contactViewModel.test">${DisplayName}</li>
</script>

<ul id="contact-list" data-bind="template: {name: 'contactsTemplate', foreach:contacts}">
</ul>
```

and the following ModelView:

```
var contactViewModel = function (contacts) {
var self = this;

self.contacts = contacts;

self.test= function () {
    console.log("CLICK");
}
```

if i use this code, the click event doesn't fire. If i create a anonymous function like:

```
<script id="contactsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="click: function(){contactViewModel.test()}">${DisplayName}</li>
</script>
```

i get the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (contacts) {
 var self = this;
 self.contacts = contacts;
 self.test= function () {
     console.log("CLICK");
 }
} has no method 'test'
```

**SOLUTION**

the solution is: $parent.

```
data-bind="click: $parent.test"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `contactViewModel` function is a constructor function, however, you are trying to use it like an instance of an object that has been constructed via the function. Your `contactViewModel` exposes an array of contacts which you are binding to the `contactsTemplate` template. For this reason, the 'context' of all bindings within this template are the object instances within your array. To bind to a function on the parent object, i.e. the `contactViewModel`, use the Knockout 2.0 parent pseudo-variable:

```
data-bind="click: $parent.test"
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work, it breaks up, after he adds the first element. My binding: ko.applyBindings(new contactViewModel(contacts), $("#contact")[0]);

Comment: @KaffeeBohne - ah ... i see your problem. I have updated my answer.